# Why wont my Google Apps Script code send email notifications for a google calendar event to guests?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I have a sreadhseet listing dates and times of meetings, emails of guests and meeting codes. I want to create a function to automatically add this to google calendar and NOTIFY guests.
Currently the event is setting up okay but there are two issues:

1. The guests dont receive an email to tell them the meeting as usual in Google Calendar
2. If not all of C5:G11 is comlplete an error message comes up- I just want the code to run through all the values that are entered but leave any blank rows.

I am fairly new to Apps Script and so really appreciate any help!

Here is my code:

```
function createevent() { 
let tutorCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("922....@group.calendar.google.com")
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Student 1');
let schedule = ss.getRange("C5:G11").getValues();
console.log(schedule)
schedule.forEach(function(entry) {
  tutorCalendar.createEvent(entry[0],entry[1],entry[2], {location:     entry[4]}).addEmailReminder(2880).addGuest(entry[3]);
})
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to send an email to guests (in your situation, the guest emails are put in column "F") when your script create a new event.
- When columns "C" to "G" are not empty, you want to send an email.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function createevent() {
  let tutorCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("922....@group.calendar.google.com");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Student 1');
  let schedule = ss.getRange("C5:G11").getValues();
  console.log(schedule)
  schedule.forEach(function (entry) {
  
    // I modified the below script.
    if (entry.every(e => e.toString() != "")) { // or if (!entry.some(e => e.toString() == "")) {
      tutorCalendar.createEvent(entry[0], entry[1], entry[2], {
        location: entry[4],
        guests: entry[3],
        sendInvites: true
      }).addEmailReminder(2880);
    }

  });
}
```

- In your situation, the properties of `guests` and `sendInvites` are included in the 4th argument of `createEvent` method.
- By this modification, when all columns "C" to "G" are not empty, a new event is created using the row values. And, the email is sent to the guest emails.

#### Reference:

- [createEvent(title, startTime, endTime, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createeventtitle,-starttime,-endtime,-options)